# Header does not show on checkout page

Tags: magento2

I customized luma-theme and every thing is fine but header is not displaying on `checkout page`

Comment: This is not a issues. This works as it

Comment: But Client requirement to show header in checkout page

Comment: can you tell me how to call it i checkout page

Comment: I havent tried it but you can do so by editing layout files of checkout page

Comment: add not work for me

Comment: vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: please  any help

Answer (score 1):

Go To `app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Checkout`

**add  checkout_index_index.xm**l file in this directory structure like this

`override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml`

So it will look like this

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Checkout/override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml
```

Now Paste below code in your extended file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
</body>
```

I hope this will helpful to you

Thanks

Comment: i want to call in luma theme not other because i use luma theme

Comment: Go a head with luma but don't forget to extend your luma theme , overriding  core files is not a good practice

Comment: how to call it in luma theme  give me any idea